# Is it possible to get items from External List using Lists Web Service

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, asp.net, external-list

I am trying to get items from an external list, but I always get 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException'.
I am very new to SharePoint and have used similar approach in gettings items from SharePoint lists and it worked, I don't know what is wrong with external lists when fetching data.

This external list is getting its data source from sql table.

Please help.

Thanks,
Nikhil.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be related to authentication issues.
Do below in your DEV server (preferably)

1. Give your account full rights to the SQL server database (for the time being, just to check if its an authentication issue). Later stages, this can be modified
2. I hope the APP pool account also has full access to the SQL database.
3. Check the BCS. See its properties & administrators. Try to add EVERYONE.

All the above steps are just to ensure if its an authentication problem.

You should **never follow these permissions** anywhere except your DEV machine